# Get the Last 4 Weeks Data as averages in sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to get Last 4 weeks of data as an average in sqlserver 2008.

i have the data like 1st week with 4 records - O/P should be like average of these four records week wise similarly i need it for one month as four week of data i.e four records.
 please suggest me the sqlserver query.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT  DATEPART(W, Data_Date) AS [Week], AVG([Some_DataField]) AS AverageValue
FROM    [DataTable]
WHERE   Data_Date >= DATEADD(W, -4, GETDATE())
GROUP BY DATEPART(W, Data_Date)
```

DATEPART(W, [Date]) returns the week number for the month in context